# C++: one writer/multi reader access to an unordered_map thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, unordered-map

I would like to build an unordered_map with concurrent access from one writer and multiple read threads. The writer will ONLY INSERT a pair, not remove or update anything inserted. Is this one thread safe? Can I view the insertion operation as an atomic operation? I ran multiple tests on my code, no crash or incorrect results found.

Thx!

Comment: No, it's not safe. You will need some sort of lock to prevent a writer and a reader accessing the map at the same time. And no operations on standard library containers are atomic.

Answer (score 6):

No, this is not thread safe.  You have to make sure that no one is reading the `unoredered_map` while you are modifying it.  If, for instance, the map needs to be rehashed due to an `insert` then you could try to read data that is being modified, even though it is a different element.

The rule for this is: If you have shared data accessed by more than one thread and at least one of them is a writer, you must have synchronization.

---

This is not to say you need to block all of your readers while reading.  You can use a [`std::shared_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex) to allow multiple readers to read at the same time but it will block all readers when the writer needs to write.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about standard unordered_map, according to c++ standard: any read access to STL collection is thread-safe. Operation for writing is not thread-safe. If you mix read and write operations it is not thread safe as well.